# Lenovo ideapad 15AMN8 touchpad and keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

i have installed ubuntu 22.04.2 and all updates.
The problem is that in Bios/Efi and grub all is working.
i have read an tested a lot.
xserver-xorg-input-all
grub default entries:
i8041.nopnp, i8042nopnp=1, pci=nocrs, i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd

in dmesg or hw info i have found keyboard ps/2 and the touchpad i2c hid
if it is needed or interested i can post dmesg and or hwinfo

how knows a fix for this problem?
thanks